# A google sheet api http request with "Service account key" auth and without google/apiclient

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

[Google docs](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php) contains only examples with `google/apiclient` php library. But the library contains 14888 php files. This is too much for just one google sheet api request with the "Service account key" auth that I need.

Is there an example with a native http google sheet api request for the "Service account key" auth somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the access token from the service account without using googleapis for PHP.
- You want to use Sheets API with the retrieved access token.

In order to achieve your goal, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, please set the variables of `$private_key` and `$client_email` using your values of service account. And also, as the sample script for using Sheets API, please set `$spreadsheetId` and `$range`. In this case, for example, please share your Google Spreadsheet on your Google Drive with the email of the service account. By this, your Spreadsheet can be seen by the service account. Please be careful this.

```
<?php

$private_key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n###-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"; // private_key of JSON file retrieved by creating Service Account
$client_email = "###"; // client_email of JSON file retrieved by creating Service Account
$scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly"];  // This is a sample scope.

$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
$header = array("alg" => "RS256", "typ" => "JWT");
$now = floor(time());
$claim = array(
    "iss" => $client_email,
    "sub" => $client_email,
    "scope" => implode(" ", $scopes),
    "aud" => $url,
    "exp" => (string)($now + 3600),
    "iat" => (string)$now,
);
$signature = base64_encode(json_encode($header, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)) . "." . base64_encode(json_encode($claim, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
$b = "";
openssl_sign($signature, $b, $private_key, "SHA256");
$jwt = $signature . "." . base64_encode($b);
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl_handle, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        "assertion" => $jwt,
        "grant_type" => "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer"
    ),
]);
$res = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
$obj = json_decode($res);
$accessToken = $obj -> {'access_token'};

print($accessToken . "\n");  // You can see the retrieved access token.


// The following script is for a sample for using the access token.
$spreadsheetId = '###';  // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
$range = 'Sheet1';
$curl_test = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_test, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/' . $spreadsheetId .'/values/'. $range);
curl_setopt($curl_test, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken));
curl_setopt($curl_test, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl_test);
print($response);
```

- When you run this script, the access token is retrieved from the service account, and as a sample, the values of "Sheet1" of `$spreadsheetId` are retrieved using Sheets API.

#### References:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)
- [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

Comment: you are a god among coders. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Although this doesn't answer your question (this might be useful to others who might stumble on this 14888-file issue), please note that you can also reduce the number of classes by specifying which services to use in your composer.json file.

In your case you would need to use the following;

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "^2.7"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": "Google\\Task\\Composer::cleanup"
    },
    "extra": {
        "google/apiclient-services": [
            "Sheets"
        ]
    }
}
```

Refer to: https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient

Comment: How did I miss this?! It was right on the https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client! Thanks!